# Rsync and group by date at destination

Tags: linux, bash

I'm copying files off a flash card onto a local hard drive, but I would like to group the destination files into directories corresponding to the file modification date. Any suggestions?

```
ls -l
-rw-rw-rw- 1 admin dba 1390 Sep  6 2019 file1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 admin dba 1390 Sep  9 2019 file2

# ...magic rsync process...

/mnt/c/2019-09-06/file1
/mnt/c/2019-09-09/file2
```

Comment: Sort is just a way to display the files. Your example shows extra created subdirectories - is that what you meant by "sorting"?

Comment: Specifically, I want to move the files by date from a removable media device onto a hard drive in directories by their date.  The default Lightroom input uses this same mechanism.  It imports the files into folders by date.  All the files get copied into a folder year-month-day, etc.  If I knew the names of the files beforehand, I could just specify the destination with a variable.  But that seems to remove the advantage of using rsync vs a copy.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide that information - comments can get lost.

Comment: Why would you want to use `rsync`? There's little value in doing so here.

Answer (score 3):

If the requirement does not include `rsync` and `sort`, this is possible in a `BASH` script:

```
for filename in /path/to/source/directory/*
do
    mdate=$(date -r "${filename}" +'%Y-%m-%d')
    destination="/path/to/destination/${mdate}/"
    mkdir -p "${destination}"
    cp "${filename}" "${destination}/"
done
```

Basically, this script first loops through every file in the source directory via a `for` loop. Then, it stores the modified date for the file in variable `$mdate`. Next, it defines and creates the destination directory, which is just the modified date `$mdate`. Finally, it copies the file into the destination directory.

This gives a general outline of how it can be done. Various things can be tweaked depending on the use-case (e.g. using `rsync` instead of `cp`, accounting for unusual characters in the directories, making it recursive, etc.)

Comment: Probably `cp -p` to retain the file modification time (and permissions). Oh, since `$destination` has a trailing slash you don't need another one when specifying the target.